# How to debug the MySQL error " You have an error in your SQL syntax"?

Tags: mysql, database

I keep getting an error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'details,
>   from product inner join supplier  on product.supplier_id = supplier.sup' at line 4

Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
    SELECT concat(product.stock_level)AS NumberOfStock,
    product.name,product.supplier_id,supplier.supplier_name,
    concat(address.supplier,'', town.supplier,'', post_code.supplier)as address,
    concat(email.supplier,'', contact_number.supplier)as contact details,
    from product inner join supplier 
    on product.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id

    HAVING (product.stock_level) < 5
```

Comment: @joestefanelli . thanks i have sorted that out but still getting an error, can you spot something i cant on line 4?

Comment: It looks like the below answer completely resolves this old problem. Would you consider accepting it, please? To do so, click the tick icon to the left of the answer, so it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

Your HAVING should be a WHERE instead.

HAVING is used to test the value of an aggregate function (e.g., COUNT, SUM) and would come after a GROUP BY clause.

WHERE is used to test the value of an ordinary column.

```
...
WHERE (product.stock_level) < 5
```

**EDIT**: After resolving the HAVING/WHERE, I now see this as well:

The last column in the select list should not have the comma after it, and the alias `contact details` should either be one word (`contact_details` or `ContactDetails`) or is must be escaped with backquotes to include the space (`contact details`).

```
...
concat(email.supplier,'', contact_number.supplier)as `contact details`
from product inner join supplier 
...
```

Comment: thanks i have sorted that out but still getting an error, can you spot something i cant on line 4?